# Swagger + Nest.js doesn't remove empty DTO and model

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I was creating documentation for `Nest.js` API using `Swagger`. The problem is what I removed documentation from this DTO or model, in swagger UI docs I can see it as empty object.

For example:

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class PostDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly title: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly content: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly description: string;
}
```

[image]

Also I was trying to change name of this entity, using incognito mode, reinstall `node_modules`, but it didn't work. If I change name of this entity, it also changes there. What's wrong?

What I want to do, is by removing this documentation decorators, not to see those empty objects.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to exclude a controller or an action from Swagger? https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators

Comment: I removed documentation from some DTOs and models, and I don't want to see it in UI docs as empty object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a CLI plugin provided with the @nestjs/swagger which will automatically add the annotations using reflection.

This means you NO LONGER need to individually annotate each property using `@ApiProperty()` etc.

The plugin is opt-in and not active by default.

In your `nest-cli.json` add:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger"]
  }
}
```

You can also change the default options:

```
"plugins": [
  {
    "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
    "options": {
      "classValidatorShim": false,
      "introspectComments": true
    }
  }
]
```

See https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin

Troubleshooting: if you are running in dev mode, may need to stop/start.

Comment: According to the docs we need to remove the dist folder manually in case of dev mode. Just restarting didn't help. However, all other information was helpful.